# Make a simple WinJS app default to a particular size

Tags: winjs

I'm trying to make a very small, simple app for Windows 10 using JavaScript. I've adapted the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript I wrote for the web, and the app runs successfully. I understand that Windows apps must be responsive, and I've written my CSS to accommodate any app size; I would like to **set the default size of the app** when it is first launched. How can I achieve this? There is so much documentation and none of it seems to address the simple stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello you can do that with this API:

```
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.preferredLaunchWindowingMode = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewWindowingMode.preferredLaunchViewSize;
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.preferredLaunchViewSize.height = 500;
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.preferredLaunchViewSize.width = 500;
```

If this doesn't work you can do this:

```
var view = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.getForCurrentView();
view.tryResizeView({ height: 500, width: 500 });
```

Comment: Thanks for posting a solution! Where do I put this code? I tried putting it in the `app.onactivated` function, and after `// TODO: This application has been newly launched. Initialize your application here.`, but it didn't make a difference. I'm using the template that ships with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015.

Comment: I work on WinRT platform since the first version of Windows 8, I have my tricks ;)

Comment: Well, thank you for hanging out on StackOverflow. No idea what I would have done without your help.

Comment: you're welcom, glad to help you :)